# What generic (?) tag to use for games that have no tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I would like to post a question about [makruk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makruk), for which there is currently no tag. After looking through the available tags, there seems to be a problem for users with less than 150 reps who want to ask questions about games for which no tag exists yet. [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) obviously can't be used for this. I could not find more generic tags I could use instead, e.g. `asian-boardgame` or `chess-variant`. What should a user do about tags in this type of situation?

Comment: Somehow, "identify-this-game" is often used. It works for me since it's easy to spot that it's in need of fixing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you ended up doing was probably your best course of action:

Write your question and add the closest possible tag you can find. Leave a comment to your question asking for someone to add the tag that you would like. If it is a tag that should be created, someone with sufficient Rep will come along and create it for you, if not they will switch the tag to a more appropriate existing tag.

I would also like to note that asking in the general chat room was also a good idea since you wanted to speed up the process. :)

Comment: Also note that tags don't exist until they are attached to a question. You can't preemptively create a tag. So asking a question with some other tag, then leaving a comment to have it changed to a more appropriate one is the best course of action.